# Postgresql межбазовый insert

Tags: postgresql

Имеется две базы postgresql, например dbA и dbB. Необходимо сделать insert-запрос из dbA в dbB. Обычно это делается с помощью dblink вида

```
-- На dbB
insert into ...
select from dblink('коннект к dbA','select запрос')
```

Второй вариант, "одно в другом"

```
-- На dbA
dblink_exec('коннект к dbB', 
'insert into ... select from dblink('коннект к dbA','select запрос')')'
```

Но есть проблемка: Доступ от dbB к dbA запрещён на уровне сети, а наоборот разрешен. Есть ещё способы это провернуть в одностороннем порядке?

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант не заработает, так как вложенный `dblink` выполняется на удаленном сервере, а в вашем случае доступа от dbB к dbA нет.

Массовый `insert` сделать не получится. В вашем случае нужно в базе bdB пройти курсором по всем записям вашего `select` и по значениям каждой строки строить `insert` и выполнять через `execute`. То есть должна формироваться строка вида:

```
dblink('коннект к dbB','insert into tmp (a,b) values (значение a, значение b)')
```

Comment: Второй вариант само собой не заработает, просто как пример привёл, когда нужно инициировать insert на одной базе из другой. В принципе проблему решил административным способом - надавили на безопасников, те открыли доступ. А так да, кроме курсора тоже ничего лучше придумать не могу.

Comment: Если вам зашел dblink посмотрите https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/postgres-fdw